# Checked remote service exception translated to StatusCodeException in tomcat

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I've got a GWT app that does regular RPC calls to a RemoteService whose methods may throw a ServiceException:

```
public class ServiceException extends Exception implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ServiceException() {}
    public ServiceException(final Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
    public ServiceException(final String errorMsg) {
        super(errorMsg);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine in development mode where I get the expected exception messages in my onFailure async callback but when I compile the app and deploy it to tomcat my exception gets translated to

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.StatusCodeException: 500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details
```

Just as in dev mode, my server logs show the expected exception reason which I logged myself just before throwing the ServiceException.

I've looked this up in google but could not find anything relevant.

(I'm working on Mac OS X Lion with GWT 2.4, java 1.6 and Tomcat 7.0.16)

Comment: Post the client side code where you check the type of the exception

Comment: for debugging purposes, the client-side code is:    `public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) { setErrorMessage(arg0.toString()); }` this displays the string into a label field in my app.

Comment: I found that exception is properly received in the client side. Refer this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC#exceptions) to check if your implementation is right

Comment: I followed exactly the steps in the tutorial; you can see the declaration of my exception and the service interface methods throws the ServiceException. As I said, the exception is properly received in dev mode, it's only when compiled and running in tomcat that it is translated

Comment: Just for the debugging purpose, you can check the type of the exception by using `caught instaceof ServiceException` in the client code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I finally figured out that the problem came from an accidental typo in the configuration of the java obfuscator I am using. Because of that my class name was renamed when building the war that I was deploying in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your gwt-rpc servlet does not handle the exception properly. Then your tomcat container handles the exception by sending the http-500 error page. Usually an exception should result in a http-200 response and "EX" in the end of the gwt encoded answer. The development mode runs with some kind of jetty container. Maybe there is some difference between the development mode's jetty and tomcat that causes the different behaviour.

Please look at your gwt-rpc servlet code to find the reason.

btw: It is a bad idea to put the error cause into a field of your exception. You'll never know if the cause is serializable or not.